# fit a custom distribution on univariate data in matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, data-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have one dimensional data like `Y=[ . . . .. ]`. I want to fit a custom distribution, Porter-Thomas, to the data histogram and find its parameter `v`. I tried to use `mle`, but it gave me the following error: "the pdf function returned negative or zero values".

This is my function:
[image]

My code:

```
f=@(v,y)((v./(2*0.99)).^(v/2)).*(y.^(v/2 -1)).*exp(-v.*y./(2*0.99))./gamma(v/2);
V=mle(Y,'pdf',f,'Start',rand,'lowerbound',[0],'upperbound',[1]);
h=histfit(Y,50);

hold on
bins=linspace(min(Y),max(Y),105);
plot(bins,f(bins,V),'r--')
```

How can I fit this distribution?

[image]

Comment: distribution function gives complex number !!! Is it normal??

Comment: No, it's not. Maybe you can plot your function to check if it is behaving normally.

Comment: yes,i plotted it, it has singularity around zero!

Comment: I think that might be a problem for the minimization function `mle` called internally. You can also attach the plot to your question.

Comment: The order of arguments of your function is reversed; should be `f=@(y,v) ...`. See [this example on offical matlab document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html#bulk4dl-7)

Comment: Have you ever heard the name of this distribution (Porter-Thomas)?

Comment: To me it looks like Gamma-distribution, which, indeed, might have singularity at 0